# X-Frame-Options header doesnt set to nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, x-frame-options, x-content-type-options

My site is on nginx server. Im add to the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

The headers is not appear on the site:

[image: The headers is not appear on the site]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more about your `nginx.conf` file, but you can add this directives into your `server` block:

```
server {
    
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # ...
}
```

Maybe located at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf`.

As indicated in the `http` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    
    # ...

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```